# I'm trying to make a user enter 10 names and make them into a list and remove the even words in the said list

Tags: python, list, typeerror, output-formatting

```
name1 = str (input("Please Enter a Name:"))

lista = []
lista.append(name1)
if name1 % 2 == 0:
    lista.remove(name1)
```

This is the part where my code messes up it says " TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: Why are you checking if a *string* `name` is even?

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = []
for i in range(10):
    lista.append(str(input("Please Enter a Name:")))

for name in lista:
    if len(name) % 2 == 0:
        lista.remove(name)

# driver code to test
print(lista)
```

Example input: a b cc d gg e ggg ff

Output: ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'ggg']

However, this could be even more simplified, by checking the length of provided input as it's provided, and adding only odd-length words instead. Saves you one loop. Here's the code:

```
lista = []
for i in range(10):
    word = str(input("Please Enter a Name:"))
    if not len(word) % 2 == 0:
        lista.append(word)

# driver code to test
print(lista)
```

Comment: I did this but it only prints the name10 or the variable at name10

Comment: maybe because i intend to have a separate 10 inputs instead of 10 in 1 go

Comment: No worries, you haven't clarify that part, i've added another solution for you.

Comment: thank you it works now sorry for the miscommunication on my part

Comment: No problem, reading your other comments, my first solution allows you to get full original list before removing (if you print it before 2nd for loop), whereas the second solution is a little more efficient

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that the `%` operator on a `str` is for formatting; the arguments to the operator (everything to the right of it) need to correspond to formatting directives inside the string.  You're trying to use it as the `int` modulus operator, which doesn't work because it's a `str`.

If your intent is to filter based on whether the *length* of the string is odd or even, use the `len()` function on the string, as others have suggested:

```
odd_names = []
for _ in range(10):
    n = input("Please Enter a Name:")
    if len(n) % 2:
        odd_names.append(n)
```

Note that you don't need to convert the result of `input()` to a `str`, and that you can simply use `len(n) % 2` to see if `len(n)` is odd (because 1 is true and 0 is false).

With a reasonably current version of Python you can do this all in a single easy list comprehension:

```
odd_names = [n for _ in range(10) if len(n := input("Please Enter a Name:")) % 2]
```